# 404 Error in user response to user authentication api IOS

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have a Uber like taxi solution. I am facing a problem with the user authentication API in iOS. The same API is working for Android.
I am an Android developer and not so familiar with iOS.
But my developer says it is due to some expired key parameter which is not accepted.

Comment: What you just mentioned is the problem statement. We would require to see your code.

Comment: And since you have worked with already working android code, you can compare the android parameters with those used in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

There must be a wrong parameter or url issue. It can be possible on typing a path api. Match the url and parameter keys with android.